# Why Migration Assistant does not migrate browser cookies?

Tags: migration, migration-assistant, cookies

If Migration Assistant migrates the entire hard disk content, it should include the browser cookies as well.

But my new machine did not have cookies; I was signed out of all web applications.

Why is that so?

Comment: Migration assistant doesn’t migrate everything. The title seems to ask one question and then your question states the opposite (or answers no). Are you looking for information about one specific browser (perhaps)  or just confirmation to use a bootable backup or image to get a clone?

Comment: web applications could well check other things than just cookies e.g. OS version so they ask you to re login

Comment: @Mark I was logged out of my own website, which only look at the session id in cookie.

Comment: @bmike so migration assistant specifically does not migrate browser cookies (even though it migrates application caches / preferences)?